# how can view all three subcategory in same line(found ex: and code)

Tags: views

i use the code to view subcategory on category page

```
<?php
if(is_category()) {

    $breakpoint = 0;
    $thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
    $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );

    $items='';
    if(!empty($subcategories)) {
        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
        $items .= '
        <div class="sidebar">
        <span class="sidebar_content"><a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="">'.$subcat->name.'</a></span>
        </div>';
        }
        echo "$items";
    }
    unset($subcategories,$subcat,$thiscat,$items);
}
?>
```

the resut of this code

subcategory1

subcategory2

subcategory3

subcategory4

subcategory5

subcategory6

subcategory7

subcategory8

subcategory9

i want the result like this

```
subcategory1 * subcategory2 * subcategory3 (all three in same line)
subcategory4 * subcategory5 * subcategory6
subcategory3 * subcategory8 * subcategory9
```

how can i do that thanks

Comment: Please do the readers of your question one big favor: Make it easy for them. Use proper lower- and uppercase letters, write full sentences, etc. Hint: There's an "edit"-button.

Comment: Spellcheckers for the win. Can you explain how this is a WordPress question and not a generic CSS grid system question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea a bit unclear but I think I understand what your trying to achieve.  It's displaying that like most likely due to css.  You could target it with a CSS3 pseudo-selector

```
.sidebar a { float: left; }
.sidebar a:nth-child(4n-0) { clear: left; }
```

OR.. this might work, no promises though because I can't see your css.

```
if(is_category()) {

$thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
$subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );

$items='';
$breakpoint = 1;
if(!empty($subcategories)) {
    $items .= '<div class="sidebar">';
    foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
        if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
        $items .= '<span class="sidebar_content"><a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="">'.$subcat->name.'</a></span>';
        if($breakpoint %3 != 0 && $breakpoint != count($subcategories) ) {
            $items .= '</div><div class="sidebar">';
        } elseif($breakpoint == count($subcategories)) {
            $items .= '</div>';
        }
        $breakpoint++;
    }
    echo $items;

}
unset($subcategories,$subcat,$thiscat,$items);
```

}

Comment: thnks for your help :) its solved